# Ideals of ring of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ring-theory, ideals

I am curious to know if the following question can be answered by my naive approach. I understand that there is a huge body of work in rings of continuous function and some really deep ideas.

**Consider the ring of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $X$ (taking $X=[0,1]$ is also fine as far as this question is concerned), denoted $C(X)$. Let $I$ be a proper ideal. Is $I=I(S)$ for some $S$, where $I(S):=\{f\in C(X)\mid  f(s)=0\, \forall s\in S\}$??**

My naive approach: We know that $I$ is contained in some maximal ideals which are of the form $I(p)$ for some point $p\in X$ according to the above notation. We take all such maximal ideals containing $I$ and intersect them. So $I\subset \bigcap I(p)=I(\bigcup \{p\})$. I was hoping to show an equality here, but I am not sure how to approach this or whether it is even true that they are equal?? I wonder if taking $f\in \bigcap I(p)$ and $f\notin I$ leads to a contradiction by breaking some maximality condition; like now we have $I\subset (I,f)\subset I(\bigcup \{p\})$ an so on...

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that such ideals are *closed* under the uniform topology. So you don’t get all of the ideals.

Comment: All **maximal** ideals are of the form $I(p)$. General ideals aren’t that easy to characterise. Check out the examples in Gillman and Jerrison’s book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example: $X=[-1,1]$. The principal ideal of $C(X)$ generated by the function $x$ has a unique $0$ the point $0$, but it does not equal $\{f \ | f(0)=0\}$.  For instance, the function $x \sin \frac{1}{x} \not \in (x)$.

Answer (score 1):

When $S$ is a singleton, it is known $I(S)$ is maximal.  The rest of the $I(S)$ ideals are then intersections of maximal ideals.

Now whether or not it is possible for all ideals to look like that depends on $X$.  If $X$ is a singleton, for example, then this is a field and yes this works.

But if $X$ is the unit interval (a connected space) then it doesn’t work.  A commutative ring in which all ideals are intersections of maximal ideals [is known to be von Neumann regular](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-ring_(ring_theory)) , this ring only has two idempotents and is not a field.